# Query Oracle for ORA-code error details

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling

**My Question:** How do you query an 11g Oracle database to get a description of an error code?

**Background:** Someone told me they had seen code once which would query oracle for details on a specific `ORA-code` error. I've been searching on Google for a little while now and can't seem to find anything like that. Does anyone know if this is possible? Is there a v$view for it or something?

**Why:** I want to write a procedure which will return the description of an error code I give to it. So when it's written I could call it like this:

```
select ora_code_desc('ORA-00000')
from dual;
```

And it would output:

```
Normal, successful completion.
Cause: An operation has completed normally, having met no exceptions.
Action: No action required.
```

Or something like that :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not accessible from SQL but within PL/SQL, you can use the `SQLERRM` function.

For example

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm(0) );
  3    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm(-1041) );
  4* end;
SQL> /
ORA-0000: normal, successful completion
ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You could, of course, build an `ora_code_desc` function that took in a string, removed the first three characters, passed the resulting number to `SQLERRM`, and returned the result

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace function ora_code_desc( p_code in varchar2 )
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(1000);
  5  begin
  6    l_str := sqlerrm( substr(p_code, 4 ) );
  7    return l_str;
  8* end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select ora_code_desc( 'ORA-00000' ) from dual;

ORA_CODE_DESC('ORA-00000')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORA-0000: normal, successful completion
```

Oracle also ships a utility on Unix platforms [oerr](http://perumal.org/oerr-the-command-line-oracle-error-code-lookup-utility/) that provides more detail-- particularly the cause and action you're looking for.  If you really want that data too, you could write a Java stored procedure that called out to an operating system shell, executed an `oerr` command, and returned the result.  That would give you more data but would, obviously, be much more complex.

Comment: Hey Justin, do you know of something which could give the error message for `AMD` errors or `NNO` or any of the [others](http://www.ora-code.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [SQLERRM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlerrm_function.htm) function.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line

```
oerr ora <error number>
```

output:

```
oerr ora 1501
01501, 00000, "CREATE DATABASE failed"
// *Cause:  An error occurred during create database
// *Action: See accompanying errors.
```

Comment: That's using oerr like Justin Cave [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11892275/971592)

Comment: Sorry I did not see Justin's answer.  To add value you can also look up

Comment: Oracle only ships `oerr` with its Unix (and Linux) flavours.  Although eager volunteers have written for versions for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness, I would like to point out that the Oracle documentation does contain a complete list of all errors, not just the `ORA` ones.  These also contain an explanation and suggested action [like the `oerr` utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892336/146325).

I know developers prefer writing queries rather than RTFM.  But if you feel like being retro you can [find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/toc.htm).