# SQLERRM - like function for other error types

Tags: sql, oracle, function

This is a continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892043).

**My Question:** I'm looking for a function like [SQLERRM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlerrm_function.htm) which will give me a description for all Oracle error codes.

From [this website](http://www.ora-code.com/), I found this list of oracle error types:

```
AMD, AUD, CLS, DBV, DGM, DRG, EXP, IMG, IMP, KUP, LCD, LFI, LPX, LRM,
LSX, NCR, NID, NMP, NNC, NNF, NNL, NNO, NPL, NZE, O2F, O2I, O2U, OCI,
ORA-CODE, PCB, PCC, PLS, PLW, PRO, QSM, RMA, SQL, TNS, UDE, UDI, VID
```

Am I misunderstanding something or is this possible?

Comment: `SQLERRM` would usually return the err description of the most recent exception.

Comment: @Annjawn, if you give it an argument it returns the text for that code.

Comment: yes with an argument. Without an argument just the recent one if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SQL> !oerr ora 04043
04043, 00000, “object %s does not exist”
// *Cause: An object name was specified that was not recognized by the system.
// There are several possible causes:
// – An invalid name for a table, view, sequence, procedure, function,
// package, or package body was entered. Since the system could not
// recognize the invalid name, it responded with the message that the
// named object does not exist.
// – An attempt was made to rename an index or a cluster, or some
// other object that cannot be renamed.
// *Action: Check the spelling of the named object and rerun the code. (Valid
// names of tables, views, functions, etc. can be listed by querying
// the data dictionary.)
```

This is the error lookup utility in Oracle.

```
Usage: oerr facility error
```

`facility` is any of the error types like `ora`, `amd` etc. and `error` is the code. But you need to make sure that you have access privilege to all installed directories.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219.pdf) is what you need in PDF format.

Comment: That's helpful, but my real need is to be able to create a function/procedure in pl/sql which I can reference in a sql statement.

Comment: I don't think that is entirely possible. For example AMD is `Oracle OLAP Catalog Metadata Messages (AMD)` which means that the PLSQL might not have all necessary Libraries to get you the error details unless you already have and use OLAP in which case you should be using OLAP libraries instead of PLSQL Libraries. Same applies for other error types. This is evident from the fact that Oracle has this `oerr` utility which is a tool (executable) and can be run from the system prompt, and depending upon the frameworks/systems you use  (installed) it can get you the error descriptions.